How to create a full XPath given a Selenium Web Element
Evidently there is a lot I don't understand about trying to generate a full XPath given a Selenium.WebElement that matches what the Google Chrome browser returns using the Inspect feature with Copy Full XPath.
I was trying to develop a class to help store the full XPath of a web element after searching through the html tree to find a web element. So the next time I need the web element I can just use the XPath and avoid the search each of the 100's of times I need it. I would code the full XPath into my code but that seems to be very brittle, akin to magic numbers.
Is there some way I can modify the Class below to be able to match what Inspect returns?
For example, in working with finance.yahoo.com, searching for historical price data, the Google Chrome Inspect feature used for a specific web element yields:
/html/body/div[2]/main/section/section/section/article/section[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/section[1]/div[2]
For the same web element, my class yields:
/html/body/div[3]/main/section[1]/section[1]/section[2]/article/section[1]/div[14]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[2]
Please find my SeleniumXPath Class below:
    Option Explicit
    Private pLabel As String
    Private pXPath As String
    Private pHasAnId As Boolean
    Private pTimeStamp As Date
    Public Property Let Label(aLabel As String)
      'Set in factory
      pLabel = aLabel
    End Property
    Public Property Get Label() As String
      Label = pLabel
    End Property
    Public Property Let WebElement(anElem As Selenium.WebElement)
      'Set in factory
      Call FindFullXPath(anElem)
      pTimeStamp = SNow
    End Property
    Public Property Get XPath() As String
      XPath = pXPath
    End Property
    Public Property Get hasAnId() As Boolean
      hasAnId = pHasAnId
    End Property
    Public Property Get IsStale() As Boolean
      If (SNow - pTimeStamp > 1) Then
        IsStale = True
      End If
    End Property
    Public Property Get Id() As String
      Id = XPath
    End Property
    Private Sub FindFullXPath(ByVal anElem As Selenium.WebElement)

      'A helpful discussion can be found in
      '  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lr7CFZEI2YA

      Dim anId As String
      Dim finished As Boolean
      Dim aTag As String
      Dim ancestorElem As Selenium.WebElement
      Dim anXPath As String
      Dim anElemArr As Selenium.WebElements
      Dim aCount As Long
      Dim k2 As Long

      On Error Resume Next

      'Attempt to retrieve the WebElement unique ID
      anId = anElem.Attribute("id")

      If (anId = "") Then

        'A unique ID was not found so, from the given element
        '  traverse the html tree backwards to map the full path

        Do While (Not finished)
          aTag = anElem.tagName
          If (aTag = "html") Then
            finished = True
          Else
            Set ancestorElem = anElem.FindElementByXPath("..")
            If (anXPath <> "") Then
              anXPath = "/" & anXPath
            End If
            Set anElemArr = ancestorElem.FindElementsByTag(aTag)
            aCount = anElemArr.Count
            If (aCount > 1) Then
              For k2 = 1 To aCount
                If (anElemArr.item(k2).Equals(anElem)) Then
                  Exit For
                End If
              Next k2
              anXPath = aTag & "[" & k2 & "]" & anXPath
            Else
              anXPath = aTag & anXPath
            End If
            Set anElem = ancestorElem
          End If
        Loop
        pXPath = "/html/" & anXPath

      Else

        'A unique id was found, use it instead of the full
        '  XPath

        pHasAnId = True
        pXPath = anId

      End If

      Call Err.Clear

    End Sub


Full xpaths from browser are brittle. Try to anchor the target element to an ancestor having an id attribute or a fixed text

Thanks LMC. The reason for my class was to mitigate the brittleness of hard coding an XPath. ID's seem far and few between. I am already using the "fixed text" method you mention but it is used in junction with exhaustive searches. If I had an accurate XPath reversal method, after searching to find an element, my hope is to temporarily store its XPath to use in finding the element 100's of times.

You say you want to generate an XPath to serve as a way to locate an element you've found by "searching through the html tree to find a web element". How do you do that search? What is the nature of that search?

In general, a so-called "full" XPath (consisting purely of location steps with numeric positional predicates where needed) is usually not a good way to identify an element that you might want to come back to, especially for modern web pages which are often updated dynamically by JavaScript and whose changing structure invalidates such an XPath. It's impossible to say what your actual problem is without seeing the HTML involved, though; please include a code block containing HTML, or at least a URL to an example page. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

If your initial "exhaustive search" is searching for elements containing particular text strings, you could implement that search in XPath, which would be less brittle than a long location path like the kind of XPath expression that a web browser developer console would construct.
